# Want to leave health community on SE

Tags: support, bug

I want to leave health community while I'm unable to ask questions.
I don't know why there's saying **You have reached your question limit** 
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.
So I want to delete it asap it became useless and helpless. That's disadvantage of SE.  Quickly delete my profile I can't do it myself.

Answer (score 2):

You're active on a few other sites, so a basic answer here would be to simply not visit the Health stack if you no longer wish to participate.

You might want to refer to:
[Why won't the system allow me to ask questions for several days?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271542/why-wont-the-system-allow-me-to-ask-questions-for-several-days)

For some more information on this message, which states in part:

> You're getting this message because you've asked at least a few questions, some of which have not been very well received by the community. In order to try to prevent you from eventually hitting a much longer-term restriction on asking questions, the system is asking that you wait for a short time before asking again. Here are a couple of ways you could spend the extra time:
>
> •Why not do a bit more research on what you're thinking about asking? It's good to get in the habit of asking questions only when you really need to, and making those questions really count when you do. Take some notes in your editor as you work through your problem some more. These notes will really help you ask a better question when your limit is up.
>
> •Take a look at some of your previous questions. Read them out loud to yourself (quietly, of course, or your coworkers might begin moving away from you). Do they read well? Is all of the information someone would need to answer your question provided within the question itself? Have you used proper capitalization, punctuation, and grammar to the best of your ability?

If you still wish to remove your Health account, here's the link

[Help - Delete your account](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)

> **How do I delete my account?**
>
> User deletion is irreversible! By sending this request, your votes will be revoked, and all of your content will be made anonymous.
>
> If you have voted or posted, please contact the Stack Exchange Team:
>
> Visit the [contact form](https://health.stackexchange.com/contact) and select 'I need to delete my user profile.' After you contact us, the team will reach out with further instructions.